# How to create object from array of containing months and years

Tags: javascript, arrays, timestamp, javascript-objects

I'm trying to create a function that will return object containing year and corresponding months, for example I have the following array:

```
const diff= [November 2022", "December 2022", "January 2023", "February 2023", "March 2023", "April 2023", "May 2023", "June 2023", "July 2023"];
```

I need to create object like this:

```
const timeFrames = [
   {
     "label": 2022,
      months: [
       {
        "label": "November",
       },
       {
        "label": "December",
       }
      ]
    },
 {
   "label": 2023,
    months: [
      {
        "label": "January",
      },
      {
        "label": "February",
      },{}
    ]
}
```

The diff array is dynamic and is created by getting the month and year between 2 dates(ms), like this:

```
var monthNames = [
  "January",
  "February",
  "March",
  "April",
  "May",
  "June",
  "July",
  "August",
  "September",
  "October",
  "November",
  "December"
];

function diff(from, to) {
  var arr = [];
  var datFrom = new Date("1 " + from);
  var datTo = new Date("1 " + to);
  var fromYear = datFrom.getFullYear();
  var toYear = datTo.getFullYear();
  var diffYear = 12 * (toYear - fromYear) + datTo.getMonth();

  for (var i = datFrom.getMonth(); i <= diffYear; i++) {
    arr.push(monthNames[i % 12] + " " + Math.floor(fromYear + i / 12));
  }

  return arr;
}
var start = 1673475048789; // example of start date

var monthYear = new Date(start).toLocaleString("en-us", {
  month: "long",
  year: "numeric"
});
var end = 1689908071000; //example of end date
var endhYear = new Date(end).toLocaleString("en-us", {
  month: "long",
  year: "numeric"
});

console.log(diff(monthYear, endhYear)); // returns diff arr values
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/javascript-forked-p5ypz9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: You can do the grouping at the same time as you create the diff, or if you want the plain diff array it's just a 'group by' on year.

Comment: Here's a quick [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-forked-9kokpl?file=/index.js) including the grouping in the `diff()` function